# In herding, what is meant by a "flank" and what are the different types?

Tags: dogs, herding

In herding, what is meant by a "flank" and what are the different types? It is easy to see that there are a couple of different types of flanks, one going clock-wise and one going counter clock-wise but I've also heard of "clean" flanks and "inside" flanks. Is there a good description of each of these and what they mean?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at all an animal expert, but to flank someone means to go around their side, so I would imagine flanking in the context of herding would involve moving around one side of a herd of animals so that they don't go in that direction; that side would feel "closed off" to them, and they would instinctively move in the other direction (if you flank them on the right, they would move left, for example).